# sensor esp8266 with arduino wont loop anymore

Tags: arduino-esp8266

Do forgive me as i am new to programming.

I used a sample code I found online for dht22 and have added other sensors in my esp8266. However, when i added the code necessary for the latest sensor (waterproof temp sensor), it doesn't activate the loop. the serial monitor prints out one sensor reading but it stops there

---

12:03:50.208 -> WiFi connected - ESP IP address: ****

12:03:50.208 -> Attempting MQTT connection...connected

12:03:55.499 -> { "temperature": " 23.72", "humidity" : " 56.70", "soilmoisture" : "99", "soiltemperature" : " 22.00"}

---

I looked around and deleted the code for the temp sensor one by one and i have discovered that when i changed the

---

char data[80] to char data[100]

---

the code starts working again but now it is looping every milisecond or something instead of 10s that i have assigned

```
// Loading the ESP8266WiFi library and the PubSubClient library
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Uncomment one of the lines bellow for whatever DHT sensor type you're using!
//#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321

//For capacitive soil sensor
const int AirValue = 865;   //you need to replace this value with Value_1
const int WaterValue = 590;  //you need to replace this value with Value_2
int soilMoistureValue = 0;
int soilmoisturepercent= 0;

// GPIO where the DS18B20 (soil temperature) is connected to
const int oneWireBus = D3;   

// Change the credentials below, so your ESP8266 connects to your router
const char* ssid = "****";
const char* password = "****";

// Change the variable to your Raspberry Pi IP address, so it connects to your MQTT broker
const char* mqtt_server = "****";

// Initializes the espClient
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

// DHT Sensor
const int DHTPin = 5;

// Initialize DHT sensor.
DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature sensor 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

// Timers auxiliar variables
long now = millis();
long lastMeasure = 0;

char data[100];

// Don't change the function below. This functions connects your ESP8266 to your router
void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("WiFi connected - ESP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

// This functions is executed when some device publishes a message to a topic that your ESP8266 is subscribed to
// Change the function below to add logic to your program, so when a device publishes a message to a topic that 
// your ESP8266 is subscribed you can actually do something
void callback(String topic, byte* message, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived on topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print(". Message: ");
  String messageTemp;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)message[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)message[i];
  }
  Serial.println();
}

// This functions reconnects your ESP8266 to your MQTT broker
// Change the function below if you want to subscribe to more topics with your ESP8266 
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
     /*
     YOU  NEED TO CHANGE THIS NEXT LINE, IF YOU'RE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH MQTT MULTIPLE CONNECTIONS
     To change the ESP device ID, you will have to give a unique name to the ESP8266.
     Here's how it looks like now:
       if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
     If you want more devices connected to the MQTT broker, you can do it like this:
       if (client.connect("ESPOffice")) {
     Then, for the other ESP:
       if (client.connect("ESPGarage")) {
      That should solve your MQTT multiple connections problem

     THE SECTION IN loop() function should match your device name
    */
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
      Serial.println("connected");  
      // Subscribe or resubscribe to a topic
      // You can subscribe to more topics (to control more LEDs in this example)
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

// The setup function sets your DHT sensor, starts the serial communication at a baud rate of 115200
// Sets your mqtt broker and sets the callback function
// The callback function is what receives messages and actually controls the LEDs
void setup() {
  dht.begin();
  // Start the DS18B20 sensor
  sensors.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

// For this project, you don't need to change anything in the loop function. 
// Basically it ensures that you ESP is connected to your broker
void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  if(!client.loop())
     /*
     YOU  NEED TO CHANGE THIS NEXT LINE, IF YOU'RE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH MQTT MULTIPLE CONNECTIONS
     To change the ESP device ID, you will have to give a unique name to the ESP8266.
     Here's how it looks like now:
       client.connect("ESP8266Client");
     If you want more devices connected to the MQTT broker, you can do it like this:
       client.connect("ESPOffice");
     Then, for the other ESP:
       client.connect("ESPGarage");
      That should solve your MQTT multiple connections problem

     THE SECTION IN recionnect() function should match your device name
    */
    client.connect("ESP8266Client");
    
  now = millis();
  // Publishes new temperature and humidity every 30 seconds
  if (now - lastMeasure > 10000) 
  
  {
    lastMeasure = now;
    
    // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
    float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

    //put Sensor insert into soil
    float sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    soilmoisturepercent = map(sensorValue, AirValue, WaterValue, 0, 100);
    float s = soilmoisturepercent;

    //sensor soil temperature code
    sensors.requestTemperatures(); 
    float temperatureC = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    //float temperatureF = sensors.getTempFByIndex(0);  
 
    // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
    // 
    if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f) || isnan(soilmoisturepercent) || isnan(temperatureC)) 
    {
      Serial.println("Failed to read from sensors!");
      return;
    }
    
    // Computes temperature values in Celsius
    float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);
    static char temperatureTemp[7];
    dtostrf(hic, 6, 2, temperatureTemp);
    
    static char humidityTemp[7];
    dtostrf(h, 6, 2, humidityTemp);
    
    static char soilmoist[7];
    dtostrf(soilmoisturepercent, 6, 2, soilmoist);

    static char soiltemp[7];
    dtostrf(temperatureC, 6, 2, soiltemp);    
    
    String dhtReadings = "{ \"temperature\": \"" + String(temperatureTemp) + "\", \"humidity\" : \"" + String(humidityTemp) + "\", \"soilmoisture\" : \"" + String(soilmoisturepercent) + "\", \"soiltemperature\" : \"" + String(soiltemp) + "\"}";
    dhtReadings.toCharArray(data, (dhtReadings.length() + 1));
    
    client.publish("room/temperature", temperatureTemp);
    client.publish("room/humidity", humidityTemp);
    client.publish("room/soilmoisture", soilmoist);
    client.publish("room/soiltemperature", soiltemp);
    
    // Publishes Temperature and Humidity values
    client.publish("/esp8266/dhtreadings", data);
    Serial.println(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: The second parameter of `String.toCharArray()` is supposed to be the size of the array you're copying to (so that it can avoid running off the end of the array).  There's no need to tell it the length of the String being copied, as the String already knows its own length.  It looks like the worst-case length for the string is about 108 characters, so even `char data[100];` isn't quite enough to hold it.

Comment: @jasonharper Im assuming the 108 characters wont be able to work anymore if i add more sensors into my esp8266? If yes, could you advice me or point me to a guide on how to determine the string length of my array and also what i could do to avoid repeating this mistake in the future?

Comment: It's possible that you might not need the `data` buffer at all; just pass `dhtReadings.c_str()` to `publish()`.  The potential problem with this is that `publish()` might require the pointer to remain valid after the call, which wouldn't be the case with `c_str()` - I couldn't find any statement one way or the other in a quick search of the PubSubClient docs.  The alternatives would be to dynamically allocate `data`, or to do a better job of keeping the size of `data[]` updated when you add fields to this message.

Comment: Thank you so much! appreciate the responce and ill try to follow your advice.